# Awk - remove line if $2 contains string

Tags: text-processing, awk

I want to remove the entire line if $2 contains a string,

string example = " hello123 "

Example of input:

```
Hey:hello123
Hey:hello
```

Expected output:

```
Hey:hello
```

Comment: by "remove" do you mean edit the file, or remove it from a pipeline stream?

Comment: you might also take a moment to explain why `grep -v :hello123` isn't a good fit for you

Comment: so remove from pipeline stream using < input.txt > output.txt

Comment: @JeffSchaller because hello123 is just a example, so hello123 could be wrapped by 123hello123333 and I would still want to remove it

Comment: thank you; some representative input & output (in the question) would make sure Answerers are going the right direction. Thank you, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input.txt awk -F: '$2 !~ "hello123"' >output.txt
```

Set `:` as the field separator, print all lines where the second column does not contain `hello123`

---

If this is going to be part of a script it may be beneficial to pass a shell variable to awk with your search pattern:

```
var='hello123'
awk -F: -v pattern="$var" '$2 !~ pattern' input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: or variably, `awk -F: -v text="hello123" '$2 !~ text'`

Comment: Use a straight string comparison with `$2 != "hello123"` in case the _actual_ string happens to contain ERE characters.  (on second reading: "contains", ok).

Answer (score 0):

```
Command

First method

sed -n -i '/^Hey:hello123$/!p'  filename


output

cat filename
Hey:hello


second method

python

#!/usr/bin/python

    import re
    k=open('l.txt','r')
    u=open('o.txt','w')
    for i in k:
        if "Hey:hello123" not in i:
            u.write(i)

output
cat o.txt 
Hey:hello


Third method

 awk -F ":" '$2 != "hello123" {print $0}' filename

    If you want to replace in orginal file use below method

    awk -F ":" '$2 != "hello123" {print $0}' l.txt >temperory && mv temperory filename


    output

    Hey:hello
```

Comment: you were thrown off by the same thing Jesse was; the OP clarified that field 2 should not *contain* the value, not just *equal* the value

Comment: OK will add another method i didnt see